# Why I can keep scrolling with scaled background image (parallax effect) on the iPhone?

Tags: html, tailwind-css, parallax

I'm trying to build a one page application with an animated background and with a parallax effect.

For desktop it works fine, but when I tested it with my iPhone, I can keep scrolling down until the background finishes (it is overscaled for the parallax effect) I pluged in my iPhone to debug the problem and it has to be the class `.parallax_wrapper` which contains the background image and the rest of the app.

**MainPage.jsx**

```js
export const MainPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div className="parallax_wrapper">
        <img className='background' src={background} alt="bg" />
        <div id='intro' className="snap">
          <IntroductionView />
        </div>
        <div id='portfolio' className="snap">
          <PortfolioView />
        </div>
        <div id='cv' className="snap">
          <CVView />
        </div>
        <div id='contact' className="snap">
          <ContactView />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**MainPage.css**

```css
.parallax_wrapper{
    scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 5px;

}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(9);
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .snap {
        scroll-snap-align: center;
    }
}
```

If I downscale the background image, the problem of the scrolling doesn't happen, but it will not cover the page, so it has to be related to the background image height that surpasses the page.

What I don't understand is that in desktop that problem doesn't happen, you scroll until the end of the `ContactView` component, not until the end of the image. It only happens to me on mobile.

Is there a way to force the app to scroll only the content of the `parallax_wrapper` except the background image?

Comment: Have you tried on desktop with reducing the browser to minimal width to see how it behaves without the media rule `min-width: 768px`? On most browsers you can simulate a phone display from the developper tools, have you tested to see if the problem is there too?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it works fine. Same as in desktop. It only happens when you use a real phone.

Comment: Which iPhone browser are you using? Are you seeing this behavior on Android devices or emulators?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an Android phone to test it. On emulators on my pc, it works fine. The thing is that in PC it only lets me scroll until the end of ContactView component, but on my iPhone it lets me scroll until the end of ParallaxWrapper (which contains the background image and is far below ContactView component)